# jQuery: is there a bug in how jQuery.ui.sortable ajax:update sends data?

Tags: jquery

code: http://jsfiddle.net/WRppV/4/

I should get something like

```
"content"=>
    ["141", ["203", "206", "204", "205"],
     "142", ["215", "207"]]
```

but i get

```
  Parameters: {"action"=>"sort_contents", "content"=>"207,215", "controller"=>"contents"}
```

Which are the last two values in the array.... I should be getting everything shouldn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) function which gets called to parse the `data` option with `jQuery.ajax`.  Looks like from the jsFiddle that you are using jQuery 1.3.2.  In 1.3.2 the `jQuery.param` function didn't handle deep objects like you are creating here.  In 1.4 `jQuery.param` was updated to handle deep object.

Try upgrading to 1.4 and it should help.